# Linked Server ERROR while trying to insert some rows into remote table

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm trying to insert some rows from local table, to a remote table.

```
begin distributed tran
begin try
    insert into [ali\servername].[dbname].[dbo].[mytable] select col1, col2 from mytable;
    commit
end try
begin catch
    print 'fail'
    rollback tran
end catch
```

But I get this error :

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ali\servername" returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

I found [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269495/prb-multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors-when-opening-ado-c) but there is no way to fix problem in SSMS. Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try doing this in reverse? Perform the insert locally and do your select remotely?

Comment: @JasonB. in reverse?! i want to insert in a linked server's table. how can i select from local within remote server?

Answer (score 1):

For linked servers you have to executed like this (specify columns you are inserting into):

```
insert into [ali\servername].[dbname].[dbo].[mytable] 
(col1, col2)
select col1, col2 from mytable;
```